# emacs lisp execute random command

Tags: colors, eval

I want to change my colour scheme to a random color scheme. Consider this elisp function:

```
(defun random-colour-theme () ;; written 2017-04-02
  "Pick a random colour theme."
  (interactive)
  (setq randomNumber (random 2))
  (setq randomColourScheme (nth randomNumber '(
"color-theme-dark"
"color-theme-light")))
(randomColourScheme)
  )
```

Everything works except the last line, (randomColourScheme). randomColourScheme is a string representing either "color-theme-dark" or "color-theme-light". If the command were (color-theme-dark), then it would work. How do you execute a command that is currently in a variable as a string? I don't know how to get started on this one.

Comment: Use `funcall` on `intern` of the selected string. Or (as @sds mentioned) use symbols instead of strings, in which case no need to use `intern` to get the symbol. Then your code will work fine (even in older Emacs versions that don't have function `seq-random-elt`).

Answer (score 3):

Use [`symbol`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbols.html)s instead of [`string`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Strings-and-Characters.html)s:

```
(require 'seq)
(defvar theme-selection
  '(color-theme-dark
    color-theme-light))
(defun random-theme ()
  "Pick a random colour theme."
  (interactive)
  (funcall (seq-random-elt theme-selection)))
```

See also [`funcall`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html) and [Sequence Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequence-Functions.html).

PS. Note that if you compile your function, you will get warnings about undeclared globals. You should use [`let`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Local-Variables.html) instead of `setq` for your local variables.

PPS. Older Emacsen lack `seq`, so you can roll your own:

```
(defun random-theme ()
  "Pick a random colour theme."
  (interactive)
  (funcall (nth (random (length theme-selection)) theme-selection)))
```

Comment: I am trying this. I downloaded and installed https://github.com/NicolasPetton/seq.el but it does not appear to have a function seq-random-elt. So I get "Symbol's function definition is void: seq-random-elt. --> thank you for the answer though and the suggestion to try symbols!

Comment: No need to download and install anything. Just evaluate the code in a modern emacs (wfm with e26).

Comment: You may need to `(require 'seq)` first.

Comment: @TianxiangXiong: I have `(require 'seq)` in my answer!

Comment: @sds -- yes, you do. I am running Emacs 24 at this point. I'll look into installing seq by hand.

Comment: @sds -- thanks also about the PS (let vs setq)

Comment: Currently widely deployed versions of Emacs (i.e. Emacs 23.1–24.5) don't have `seq`. (Yes, 23.1, that's the version in [CentOS 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS#End-of-support_schedule) which is still a popular distribution)

Comment: I run the newest version of Ubuntu, and apt-get (Debian) gives me Emacs 24.

Comment: okay, I added a version which does not use `seq`.

Answer (score 1):

```el
(defun random-colour-theme () ;; written 2017-04-02
  "Pick a random colour theme."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((color-schemes '("color-theme-dark"
                          "color-theme-light"))
         (random-number (random (length color-schemes)))
         (random-colour-scheme
          (nth random-number color-schemes)))
    (funcall (intern random-colour-scheme))))
```

Comment: This works! Thanks, politza and sds.

Comment: But as indicated by sds and Drew, it's pointless writing these as strings in the first place when their sole use-case requires them to be in symbol form. Unless there is some unstated reason for wanting string input then just use `(let* ((color-schemes '(color-theme-dark color-theme-light)) ...` and ditch the `intern` call.